# Alamofire install failed - Xcode 8.1

Tags: ios, swift3, alamofire, xcode8

Recently upgraded to XCode 8.1 trying to install Alamofire pod for a new project. Podfile:

```
 source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
 platform :ios, '10.0'

 target 'app' do
# Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
 use_frameworks!

# Pods for app

 pod 'Alamofire',
 :git => 'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git',
 :branch => 'swift3'

 end
```

And my terminal responds:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPjx3.png)

so what can I do?

--Update--
also tried `pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'` 
[here is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqLst.png)

I did the `pod repo update` it doesn't do anything at all

Comment: See [install Alamofire 4](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#installation) and [migration guide](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%204.0%20Migration%20Guide.md)

Comment: @EricAya well this is what I get `Analyzing dependencies
[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:

- `Alamofire (~> 4.0)` required by `Podfile`

None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `Alamofire (~> 4.0)`.

You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update`.
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.

Note: as of CocoaPods 1.0, `pod repo update` does not happen on `pod install` by default.
` pod version is 1.1.1

Comment: You should do `pod repo update` then `pod install`, this is needed to update the list of available pods.

Comment: @EricAya stuck here for a long time `Performing a deep fetch of the `master` specs repo to improve future performance` actually tried it many times it goes for even an hour.

Comment: It can be long, but one hour is very long indeed. Well then I have no idea. Let it run, maybe it will end properly eventually...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit your podFile as below and just install the pods using `pod install --verbose` command if still error exists then update your repo with `pod repo update` then try again.

```
 source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
 platform :ios, '10.0'

 target 'app' do
# Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
 use_frameworks!

# Pods for app

 pod 'Alamofire'

 end
```

Comment: Just replace app to your project name in above code.
Worked for me!!!

Answer (score 0):

As per the discussion [here](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/1556),

You need to use

```
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'
```

In your pod file

Comment: You need to remove rest of the things like git, branch from your podfile and just use the above syntax

Comment: Yes I did. but I get this: Analyzing dependencies [!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements: - Alamofire (~> 4.0)` required by Podfile None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: Alamofire (~> 4.0). You have either: * out-of-date source repos which you can update with pod repo update. * mistyped the name or version. * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile. Note: as of CocoaPods 1.0, pod repo update does not happen on pod install by default

Comment: XCode 8.1 (8B62) and pod version 1.1.1

Comment: installs Alamofire 3.4.1 and crashes so not even .xcworkspace file's been created!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem when i updated the mac os from el capitan to sierra and installed new version of Xcode.

I updated the cocoapod and still, was facing the same problem.

I found a solution by completely removing cocoapod from root directory and installing it again.

To remove the cocoapod completly use this in terminal

```
$ sudo rm -fr ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/
$ sudo rm -fr ~/.cocoapods/repos/master/
```

and then install the cocoapod again

```
$ gem install cocoapods
```